# Javascript/jQuery search xml for a string then run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I need to run a function `matchFound()` if a string is found in an external xml file.

This is what I have so far:

```
function init(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://www.domain.com/feed.rss",
      dataType: "text",
      success: parseXml 
   });
}

function parseXml(xml){
  // look into the xml file
}

function matchFound(){
  alert('match found');
}

function matchNotFound(){
  alert('match NOT found');
}
```

But I don't know how to parse the XML and search for a string.

The search location within the xml is: `rss > channel > item > title` and I only need to match the first 10 characters in that tag.

If a match is found then run the funciton `matchFound()` or if not found run the function `matchNotFound()`

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to treat the returned text as XML so the interpreter can properly parse this object.

```
dataType: "xml",
```

Now in your `parseXml` function, you need to wrap the returned result as a jQuery object, then iterate for the elements that you need.

**edit**

```
function parseXml(xml){
    var string_to_find = "Hello World!";
    $(xml).find('title').each(function(){
        var str = $(this).text();
        if(str.indexOf(string_to_find) > -1){
            if(matchFound(str, string_to_find)){
                return false;   
            }
        }

    });
}
function matchFound(str, string_to_find){
    alert('Match found in string - '+ str +'\r\n While looking for the string- '+ string_to_find);
    return true;
}

function matchNotFound(){
    alert('No Match found!');   
}
```

And [here is a jsFiddle illustrating](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMTC9/) this functionality.

Comment: Awesome Thanks, I changed the dataType but for some reason the `parseXml` function is not running. any ideas?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it stop searching after it finds a match? I dont; want it to run the `matchFound` function over and over again. Thanks again, C

Comment: @Cybercampbell In my revision above, certain aspects can be omitted for your own use, such as passing `str, stringtofind` to the function,  or declaring it in the function as arguments. Note that `return true` will fire our conditional statement in the `$.each()` and `return false;` in the conditional statement is self, will force the exiting of the `$.each()` loop.

Comment: Awesome.. thanks so much.... everything is working perfectly apart from my initial ajax function. it runs but doesn't call the `parseXml` any idea's whay that's not working? can you add an external xml to your fiddle? Thanks C

Comment: @Cybercampbell Requests for data from another domain over `ajax` are subject to the `cross origin resource sharing` policy, or `CORS` for short. If your hostname is not explicitly declared in their `access control allow origin` headers, and they are not providing JSONP as an endpoint, then this will not work for you, unfortunately.

Comment: oh... crap. Ok thanks. I'll put this code aside as it perfect for other things. Thanks.

Comment: How do I do this exact thing with json instead of xml?

Comment: @Cybercampbell Attempt it yourself, when you get stuck, ask a new question. I've clearly identified the issue and resolved it here. SO is not a forum, you ask a question and someone clearly and concisely will answer it. Let's keep to the guidelines.